# How to set 100% div width in jquery cycle plugin

Tags: jquery, html, width, cycle

i have problem..
I must set width of slide div to 100%, max width of the "sklo" div.. 
See my codes below:

```
$(function () {
$('#sklo').cycle({ 
    fx:     'scrollHorz', 
    speed:  1000, 
    timeout: 0,
    slideExpr: '.slide',
    slideResize: 1
        }); 
});
```

And table

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="container">

<div id="content">

<div id="sklo">
<div class="slide">Text content 1</div>
<div class="slide">Text content 2</div>
<div class="slide">Text content 3</div>
</div>

</div>

  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

And CSS:

```
.container {
min-width:800px;
width:100%;
position:relative;
}
#sklo {
display:block;
min-width:675px;
min-height:250px;
width:100% !important;
height:100%;
border-radius:20px;
background-color:red;
}
.slide {
min-width:675px;
min-height:250px;
width:100% !important;
text-align:center;
}
```

my problem:

text content slider can't be 100% width of the "sklo" ??
How to set 100% of the .slide div?
Must be in %, no px!

Please help.

Comment: Do you have any working demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `table` width to `100%` then its `content` will `automatically` take `100% width`

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td class="container">
         <div id="content">
           <div id="sklo">
             <div class="slide">Text content 1</div>
             <div class="slide">Text content 2</div>
             <div class="slide">Text content 3</div>
           </div>    
         </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```